# Mysql conditional: case when and LEFT join cannot make them work properly

Tags: mysql

So far I've this:

```
SELECT
    l.logo_id,
    l.logo_image_path,
    l.logo_lang,
    (1) AS answered
FROM logos l
WHERE l.logo_level = $level"
```

I want answered to display 1 if user answered this question and 0 if user didn't answer this question. Results are stored inside results table which contains r.logo_id r.user_id

I tried:

```
(CASE WHEN l.logo_id = r.logo_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS answered
```

But it doesn't work, obviously I'm missing results table, and user_id check as I want this to happen for current user, so I have to add somewhere WHERE r.user_id = `$user_data[0]['user_id']`

Can you help me with this? and also explain step by step so I get it finally :)

ty.

Comment: Can you post the table declares please? Trying to work out what the r table alias refers to

Comment: @Kickstart table r is results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming logos is your questions table and results is your answers table, with each user having 0 to many rows on results table (one for each answered question) then something like this:-

```
$sql = "SELECT
    l.logo_id,
    l.logo_image_path,
    l.logo_lang,
    CASE WHEN r.logo_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS answered
FROM logos l
LEFT OUTER JOIN results r
ON l.logo_id = r.logo_id
AND  r.user_id = ".$user_data[0]['user_id']."
WHERE l.logo_level = ".$level;
```

Comment: This works perfectly. But I don't understand why... What confuses me is AND  r.user_id = ".$user_data[0]['user_id']." I expect this AND to do something like WHERE l.logo_level = ".$level;

Comment: It uses a left join. The check for r.user_id is in the ON clause of that join. This way it will only join against records on the results table for that user. If you checked for r.user_id in the WHERE clause then it would do the join and THEN exclude records which were not for that user id. However as a LEFT JOIN would have null in that field when there was no matching record (ie, when the user hadn't answered that question) you would land up excluding rows for question that user id had not answered.

Comment: Glad it did. I was struggling to explain it in a comment

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN l.logo_id = r.logo_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS answered, l.logo_id,
    l.logo_image_path,
    l.logo_lang FROM logos l, results r WHERE l.logo_level = $level AND ... clause to join two tables ... AND  r.user_id = $user_data[0]['user_id']
```

Comment: I don't get what you wrote, but I think r.user_id = $user_data[0]['user_id'] should be conditional for CASE WHEN not whole select. Some questions may not be answered and there will be nothing in results table they won't be displayed because of that conditional... I might be wrong :)

Comment: I don't get your question clearly either. Perhaps it would be better if you could provide more about the attributes in your question :)

Comment: sorry, with "I don't get what you wrote" - I meant I understand little about mysql statements, so I'm guessing most of the time...